# SQL: How do you showcase the percentage of total in a column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have to create a Movie database, and one of the queries involves showing a list of movies that a user has "rated," along with the actual rating and the Genre.

Additionally, it must show the percentage of that genre out of all the movies the user has rated. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE GENRES (
MOVIEID                         INT             NOT NULL,
GENRE                           VARCHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY(MOVIEID),
FOREIGN KEY(MOVIEID) REFERENCES MOVIES(ID)
);
```

Query:

```
SELECT U.USERID, M.TITLE, U.USERRATING, G.GENRE
FROM USER_RATEDMOVIES U, MOVIES M, GENRES G
WHERE (M.ID = U.MOVIEID) AND (U.USERID LIKE "EXAMPLE") AND (G.MOVIEID = M.ID)
ORDER BY DATE_YEAR, DATE_MONTH, DATE_DAY, DATE_HOUR, DATE_MINUTE, DATE_SECOND;
```

This returns everything I need EXCEPT the percentage of the total. That's where I get lost. I'm new with SQL and struggle with the COUNT(*) and GROUP BY.

Comment: Are you using `SQL Server` or `MySQL`? You have both tagged.

Comment: For starters you should stop using the antiquated ANSI-89 style joins and use the "newer" ANSI-92 style joins. It has been well over 20 years since the standard has been in place. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins What isn't clear to me is what you expect as output.

Comment: I am currently using MySQL. And I had no idea about those type of joins, I'm basing my code off of my instructor's material.

Comment: Ouch, your instructor is providing you with very out of date information. Shame on them!!!

Comment: Also, to answer the output question: Currently, the code produces a timeline of the user's rated movies and the rating. I would like to add an extra column of output which showcases each Genre's percentage. So if a user watched 2 action films and 2 comedies, it would show 50% for both.

Comment: @SeanLange Pre SQL-92 implicit joins is what's taught at my university too :\ I guess the teachers keep teaching what they once were taught... or maybe it's the connection to set theory that dictates it.

Comment: I am not quite sure I get you on the output. So in your 2 action and 2 comedy example you would get 4 rows of output and the percentage column would be 50% in each row? So it would be the total number of movies for the current genre divided by the total number of movies for that user?

Comment: @jpw that is just sad. I have seen so many people over the years who come out of school with a great ability to write cursors in sql server but no grasp of how to do it in a set based approach. They also very rarely teach students to use parameterized queries and lots of people leave school with the only examples of queries is the textbook injection model.

Comment: Great, cursors. No wonder so many sites take forever to render output.

Comment: Back on track here for @KyleBragg. We need to get some more details from you to help. This article would be a great place to start. https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @SeanLange exactly! So row would showcase the User, Title, Rating, Genre, and Percentage.

Answer (score 0):

The challenge of your needs is presenting unit level data with aggregate level data. Hence, consider using aggregate groupby derived tables (nested select statements in the `FROM` or `JOIN` clauses) that correlates (matches `USERID`) to your previously set up query (using explicit instead of implicit joins):

```
SELECT U.USERID, M.TITLE, U.USERRATING, G.GENRE, 
       (gdT.GENRE_COUNT / udT.RATING_COUNT) AS PERCENTAGE

FROM USER_RATEDMOVIES U 
INNER JOIN MOVIES M ON M.ID = U.MOVIEID
INNER JOIN GENRES G ON M.ID = G.MOVIEID 

INNER JOIN 
   -- COUNTS BY CORRESPONDING USER AND GENRE 
   (SELECT subU.USERID, subG.GENRE, Count(*) AS GENRE_COUNT 
    FROM USER_RATEDMOVIES subU 
    INNER JOIN MOVIES subM ON subM.ID = subU.MOVIEID
    INNER JOIN GENRES subG ON subM.ID = subG.MOVIEID 
    GROUP BY subU.USERID, subG.GENRE) AS gdT
ON gdT.USERID = U.USERID AND gdT.GENRE = G.GENRE

INNER JOIN
   -- COUNTS BY CORRESPONDING USER
   (SELECT subU.USERID, Count(*) AS RATING_COUNT 
    FROM USER_RATEDMOVIES subU 
    GROUP BY subU.USERID) AS udT
ON udT.USERID = U.USERID

WHERE  U.USERID LIKE "EXAMPLE"

ORDER BY DATE_YEAR, DATE_MONTH, DATE_DAY, 
         DATE_HOUR, DATE_MINUTE, DATE_SECOND;
```